# How should I store nested JSON object inside Cassandra?

Tags: json, cassandra

This is the first time I am working with Cassandra and I have a data structure like following, want to save it inside the Cassandra:

```
{"user_id": "123",
 "user_cards": {
  "first_card": {
    "card_number": 456
  }
 }
}
```

I searched through the internet and found an example like following:

```
use json;
CREATE type json.sale ( id int, item text, amount int );
CREATE TABLE json.customers ( id int  PRIMARY KEY, name text, balance int, sales list> );

INSERT INTO json.customers (id, name, balance, sales) 
VALUES (123, 'Greenville Hardware', 700,
[{ id: 5544, item : 'tape', amount : 100},
{ id: 5545, item : 'wire', amount : 200}]) ;
```

But I am not sure if this is the best way of doing that? I remember from my experience with MySQL or MongoDB/Mongoose, we were defining separate tables for nested JSON objects and put the Foreign key of that table inside a column of the parent table(Or do population in Mongo).

As I heard Cassandra is against normalization and it's better to do denormalization on it, I don't know what approach should I take?

Also I have another question about data compression, Will cassandra take care of it if I do something like the example I put above?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra is a column-oriented DB that stores the data as **rows**.

You will define your primary key based on the search you want to operate. Most of the time it is then *flat*

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table (
   user_id uuid,
   user_email text,
   user_name text,
   PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
```

In the table above you should query by always providing `user_id`. You can interact with Cassandra using JSON if you want as long as you validate the schema

```
INSERT INTO sample_table JSON '{
  "user_id": "1cafb6a4-396c-4da1-8180-83531b6a41e3",
  "user_email": "alice@example.org",
  "user_name": "Alice",
}';
```

Same for reads:

```
SELECT JSON user_id, user_email
FROM sample_table
WHERE user_id=1cafb6a4-396c-4da1-8180-83531b6a41e3;
```

In your examples you are introducing nested type. It is totally possible. Using something called *User Defined Type* [documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/types.html#udts)

```
CREATE TYPE user_cards (
 card_number int,
 card_index  int);
```

You can then use your type as the type of your column

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table (
   user_id uuid,
   user_email text,
   user_name text,
   cards user_cards,
   PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
```

For more nested/complex simply store the document as a TEXT.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to insert data in JSON format using the `INSERT ... JSON` CQL command. For example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name JSON '{
    "column_name": "value"
}'
```

But it is a bit more nuanced than that so allow me to explain.

Data modeling in Cassandra is the complete opposite of data modeling in traditional relational databases. Instead of working out how to store the data into tables, we first start by listing all the application queries THEN designing a table for EACH of the app queries. We do this so the tables are optimised for reads.

For example, assuming the application needs to "retrieve all cards for a user", we need to design a table such that:

- the data is partitioned by users, AND
- the cards are "clustered" (grouped together).

The table schema would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE cards_by_user (
    user_id int,
    card_number int,
    card_type text,
    card_expiry text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, card_number)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (card_number ASC)
```

In contrast to two-dimensional tables in RDBMS, this Cassandra table is multi-dimensional such that each partition (user) can have one or more rows (cards).

To create a new card entry for a user, the CQL statement to insert JSON formatted data looks like:

```
INSERT INTO cards_by_user
JSON '{
    "user_id": "123",
    "card_number": "456",
    "card_type": "visa",
    "card_expiry": "07/2028"
}'
```

You can insert multiple rows of cards using the same `INSERT` format. For example:

```
INSERT INTO cards_by_user
JSON '{
    "user_id": "123",
    "card_number": "789",
    "card_type": "mastercard",
    "card_expiry": "04/2025"
}'
```

To retrieve all the cards for a user:

```
SELECT * FROM cards_by_user WHERE user_id = 123;

 user_id | card_number | card_expiry | card_type
---------+-------------+-------------+------------
     123 |         456 |     07/2028 |       visa
     123 |         789 |     04/2025 | mastercard
```

As you can see, it is not necessary to use user-defined types (UDTs) to store the data. We recommend mapping the data to native CQL columns instead of UDTs whenever possible to reduce the level of complexity required to maintain your data and code. Cheers!